# Разбор предложения с однородными членами

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Как разбирается приведённое ниже предложение?

> Розы он поливал холодной водой, а фиалки - довольно тёплой.

Хотелось бы также узнать, нужен ли знак тире между "фиалки" и "довольно тёплой".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Розы он поливал холодной водой, а фиалки — довольно тёплой.*

Это структурно неполное предложение.  Отсутствие второстепенного члена предложения (дополнения) при наличии определения, относящегося к отсутствующему члену.

Тире поставлено на месте пропуска повторяющегося слова *водой*.

Comment: @,Людмила, по-моему,тире стоит на месте пропуска сказуемого.

Comment: А здесь и то и другое пропущено, как хочешь, так и объясняй: Розы он поливал холодной водой, а фиалки поливал  водой  довольно тёплой. На месте пропуска.